# how to do realtime update data on SPA?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA web app that was built using next js and express js, how do I update the data from an application running on computer 1 if the data is changed by computer 2 without the application on computer 1 being refreshed

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: WebSockets, long polling, WebRTC, there are lots of different ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) enables real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication.
It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed.